# Automatic Migration vs Code-base Migration

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I'm learning EF4.3 Migration, and I have read these two articles from ado.net team blog:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-code-based-migrations-walkthrough.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-automatic-migrations-walkthrough.aspx

But after reading this two articles, I still not clear what's the difference between them and when to use code-based migraion, when to use automatic migration. Anyone can guide me?

Thanks!

Comment: I hate how MS simply appropriates vocabulary.  There are those of us that think that "code migration" means "convert code from one language/platform to another" and that "automatic migration" means "do code migration automatically".

Comment: @IraBaxter reminds me of the topic of Bounded Contexts in DDD. http://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html

Comment: The links don't seem to work anymore, are there any up-to-date articles on this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Those articles are very clear so if you don't understand the difference it means that you didn't concentrate while reading the text and you also probably didn't follow the text by coding examples yourselves.

Automatic migration is just a magic tool. You run your application and you will always get your database in the latest version because EF will do implicit migration every time it is needed - in the purest version you never need to do anything more than enabling automatic migrations.

Automatic migrations are sometimes not enough. You need to add some customization to migration code or run some additional SQL commands for example to transform data. In such case you add explicit code based migration by calling `Add-Migration` command. Explicit migration shows all migration code which will be executed during migration (there is no additional magic).

If you turn off automatic migrations you must always define explicit migration to define database upgrading process in well defined explicit steps. This is especially useful for scenarios where you need to use both upgrading and downgrading to specific version.

Comment: When you @Ladislav Mrnka say "Automatic migrations are sometimes not enough" Can you point me to a list of scenarios not handled by Automatic Migrations? I have seen this statement said many times on the internet, even in the official [EF 5 documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj554735) but never is a list of limitations given.

Comment: @Steven: You will not find a list of limitation anywhere. Sometimes you for example make change which will not need only changing table structure but also transforming data - that requires code migration where you manually handle data. Sometimes you want to add some more SQL features - indices, constraints atc. Again that is possible only with code migration. Mostly anytime you need to use `Sql` or `CreateIndex` or `DropIndex` methods it calls for code migration.

Comment: EF docs example itself shows a case where an automatic migration is not enough: if you need to initialize a not null column with a value which isn't the default (i.e. 3 instead of 0 for an int column) you need to add a manual migration to specify it. Just to add another case to @LadislavMrnka's comment.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka Thanks for assuming someone is not reading well. Maybe the person simply does not understand it and needs some more explanation?

Answer (score -2):

There is more info about your question at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj554735.aspx). They don't recommend to mix automatic and code based migrations in team development scenarios. But I don't understand clearly what problems it can create.